# Python DummyRegressor with min of group

Tags: python, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

Trying to use sklearn.dummy DummyRegressor to create a baseline for my model which is a regression model with encoded categorical variables to predict a continuous target. Baseline strategy is 'min' and I'd like the min by group. Below is a reproducible example. My actual dataset is larger and it is a collection of runners ('a' ids) racing on courses ('c' ids) with the time they recorded for that performance as the target 'T'. I'm trying to see if the model performs better that the runner's best/fastest recorded time (min).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a1','c1',10],
                   ['a1','c2',15],
                   ['a1','c3',20],
                   ['a1','c1',15],
                   ['a2','c2',26],
                   ['a4','c3',15],
                   ['a2','c1',23],
                   ['a2','c2',15],
                   ['a3','c3',20],
                   ['a3','c3',13],
                   ['a1','c3',19],
                   ['a4','c3',19],
                   ['a3','c3',12],
                   ['a3','c3',20]], columns=['aid','cid','T'])

X = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['aid','cid'],prefix_sep='',prefix='')
X.drop(['T'], axis=1, inplace=True)
y = df['T']


# train test split 80-20
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regr = LinearRegression()
Lin_model = regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = Lin_model.predict(X_test)
print('R-squared:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

For comparison I'd like to use DummyRegressor. Using mean as strategy it works and as I understand it is using the mean of the entire column.

```
dummy_mean = DummyRegressor(strategy='mean')
dummy_mean.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred2 = dummy_mean.predict(X_test)
print('R-squared:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred2))
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred2))
```

to compare to the lowest T or fastest/best time I tried the constant function and defined it as min value by group

```
min_value = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['min']})
dummy_min = DummyRegressor(strategy='constant',constant = min_value)
dummy_min.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred4 = dummy_min.predict(X_test)
```

which returns

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `min_value = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['min']})` the shape of the data frame is changed to (3,1) try to change it to`min_value = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['min']}).values.reshape(1,-1)` Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @TavoGLC but the solution didn't work for me. I got the same error. When looking at my example I also realized coincidentally there are 3 groups of 'a' and that was confusing so I added a4 and now my ValueError: could not broadcast array from shape (1,4) into shape (3,1) and I get the same with or without .values.reshape(1,-1).